# Need to add a custom link “Kids” in header and open different design/layout/css in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Need to add a custom link "Kids" in header, when click on kids link, then website menus and home page design/layout/css and url should be changed new url would be ([www.site.com/kids](http://www.site.com/kids)).

Category page url like : [www.site.com/kids/category.phtml](http://www.site.com/kids/category.phtml) product url should be like : [www.site.com/product-detail.phtml](http://www.site.com/product-detail.phtml) and in product detail page link kids should not be there.

**Note:** Single Cart for all products added from default or kids product pages.

I don't want to create a new store for "Kids" because it will change the new order series for kids.

Please suggest any solution or steps to start with.

Answer (score 0):

May be these steps can help you.

- Create a **URL Rewrite** for your kids category to /kids. From
  [www.site.com/kids.html](http://www.site.com/kids.html) to [www.site.com/kids](http://www.site.com/kids), I assume you have .html
  suffix enabled.
- Add sub categories for Kids, it will have kids in the URL.
- Add Kids to the Menu and test you able to access the Kids category section without .html
- Now create a custom layout for Kids category and choose the layout from Design under category edit page

[image: Custom Layout]

- Your product URL should not have category name enabled. If enabled then maybe you can disable it from ***Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > SEO***

Please let me know if you have any further questions or I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

@sudhanshu, Thanks for solution, But there is two challenges here,
1- When we disable .html suffix then all category page will be without suffix.
and seo url with be changes.

2- Also when we click on kids link the layout can be changed but we need kids specific menus/header also.

Comment: I didn't suggest to disable .html. Just create a URL Rewrite for KIDS. And with custom page layout you can change header as well.